# Framework for handling HTTP responses in C#

Tags: c#, httpresponse, anglesharp

The project is a C# desktop application that interacts with a webpage.

The last time I did anything like this, I used WatiN and HTMLAgilityPack. But WatiN isn't very elegant as it opens a browser window to interact with the website. It's more designed for Integration Testing, still it got the job done.

This time I'm looking at AngleSharp to parse the HTML, but I still need to write code that logs into the website, presses a couple of buttons and does some POSTS.

Are there any frameworks I can use to make this straightforward?

Comment: Really silly question but don't you have the possibility to interact with a web service (a REST API by example) instead of a website ?

Comment: Not sure if this is the right place for the questsion, but what about: https://github.com/dotnetcore/DotnetSpider ?

Comment: @Arcord - nope - that would be easy. It's a webpage I have no control over.

Comment: @ Musterknabe - not really what I'm looking for, but thanks.

Comment: Using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebresponse doesn't have a view (like a browser view) so it is faster than a webpage.  the HttpWebRequest doesn't automatically add a lot of headers that are automatically added in the browser so you usually have to add missing headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - it looks like I underestimated the power of AngleSharp

There's a wonderful post [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1017190/Submitting-Forms-with-AngleSharp) which describes how to use it to log into a website, and post forms.

The library has been updated since so a few things have changed, but the capability and approach is the same.
I'll include my "test" code here which demonstrates usability.

```
public async Task LogIn()
        {
            //Sets up the context to preserve state from one request to the next
            var configuration = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithDefaultCookies();
            var context = BrowsingContext.New(configuration);

            /Loads the login page   
            await context.OpenAsync("https://my.website.com/login/");

            //Identifies the only form on the page (can use CSS selectors to choose one if multiple), fills in the fields and submits
            await context.Active.QuerySelector<IHtmlFormElement>("form").SubmitAsync(new
            {
                username = "CharlieChaplin",
                pass = "x78gjdngmf"
            });
            
            //stores the response page body in the result variable.   
            var result = context.Active.Body;
```

EDIT - after working with this for a while, I've discovered that Anglesharp.IO has a more robust HttpRequester in it. The above code then becomes

```
public async Task LogIn()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var requester = new HttpClientRequester(client);
            //Sets up the context to preserve state from one request to the next
            var configuration = Configuration.Default
                               .WithRequester(requester)
                               .WithDefaultLoader()
                               .WithDefaultCookies();

            var context = BrowsingContext.New(configuration);

            /Loads the login page   
            await context.OpenAsync("https://my.website.com/login/");

            //Identifies the only form on the page (can use CSS selectors to choose one if multiple), fills in the fields and submits
            await context.Active.QuerySelector<IHtmlFormElement>("form").SubmitAsync(new
            {
                username = "CharlieChaplin",
                pass = "x78gjdngmf"
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to interact with a web site, filling text boxes, clicking buttons etc, I think a more logical solution would be using and managing an actual web browser.

[Selenium.WebDriver NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver)

[C# Tutorial 1](https://testguild.com/selenium-webdriver-visual-studio/)

[C# Tutorial 2](http://learn-automation.com/install-selenium-webdriver-with-c/)

Comment: WatiN works in this way as explained above. I asked the question because this time I DON'T want to use a browser.